# 2 -way binding with $scope not working on newly added widgets

Tags: angularjs

On click I tried to add an input box inside the form. The newly added text has got ng-model="name". Still the name varialble is not getting populated in the textbox. I want to add widgets dynamically to the ng-controlled section and should be able to do 2-way binding with $scope variable.  Is there any way i can do this.?

```
<div ng-app = "myapp">
<div ng-controller = "HelloController" >
    <a ng-click="clickMe()">Click</a>
    <form name="studentForm" id="myform">
    <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text">
    <div ng-bind="name">
    </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var aa = angular.module("myapp", []);
    aa.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Raman";
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
            $('#myform').append('<input name="name2" ng-model="name" type="text">');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The bad praxis angular/jquery mixup

AngularJS analyzes your markup on page load. Any code which is injected afterwards is not considered by angularJS. To add new markup to angularJS you need to call the angular `$compile` service.

```
var aa = angular.module("myapp", []);
aa.controller("HelloController", function($scope,$compile) {
    $scope.name = "Raman";
    $scope.clickMe = function(){
        var insert = $compile('<input name="name2" ng-model="name" type="text">')($scope);
        $('#myform').append(insert);
    }
});
```

---

### The better angular way

But as a general hint: It is not good praxis to mix up angularJS and jQuery as shown in your code. you might simply add the input field to your html markup and show it conditionally using angularJS.

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <a ng-click="clickMe()">Click</a>
        <form name="studentForm" id="myform">
            <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text">
            <div ng-bind="name"></div>
            <input name="name2" ng-model="name" type="text" ng-show="showNameField">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var aa = angular.module("myapp", []);
    aa.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Raman";
        $scope.showNameField = false;
        $scope.clickMe = function(){
            $scope.showNameField = true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

---

### The quick and dirty angular way

Or you might even modify the variable directly in your `ng-click` directive. Further js interprets empty variables in expressions as false values, which is why you don'T even need to initialize the variable in your controller function:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <a ng-click="showNameField = true">Click</a>
        <form name="studentForm" id="myform">
            <input name="name" ng-model="name" type="text">
            <div ng-bind="name"></div>
            <input name="name2" ng-model="name" type="text" ng-show="showNameField">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var aa = angular.module("myapp", []);
    aa.controller("HelloController", function($scope) {
        $scope.name = "Raman";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you. I understand ur best practice tips.  In ur first example, it sees there is a compile error in the line starting with $compile. I tried to correct is but still not working. The new text box is still empty.

Comment: @MS I corrected the first part. May you try it again?